# Convert Normal String to bson object Id

Tags: mongodb

I have id like `533bc0f60015a0a814000001`.How can i convert bson type of Id.
I tried like

`new ObjectId("533bc0f60015a0a814000001")`

But not Working.I need to do it in via javascript

Comment: Which mongodb driver are you using?  The driver will determine what needs to be required in your javascript and the function to call. ObjectId("533bc0f60015a0a814000001") will work from the mongo shell.

Comment: What is the error? I just tried your example in the MongoDB shell and it works without an issue, see here: https://gist.github.com/comerford/dfa733ac46d564cb2580

Comment: i'm using inside jasper soft.not working